# Issue with Multi-Input Handling in React Component

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm facing an issue with a React component where I have three input fields that should handle a 9-digit code split across them. However, when I enter more than 3 digits in one input field, it doesn't shift to the next input field as expected. Similarly, if I try to paste a 9-digit code into the first input field, the other fields remain blank. Can someone help me achieve this?

my react component.

```
export default function VoucherPage() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [secret, setSecret] = useState<string>("");
  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState<SecretCode>({
    input1: "",
    input2: "",
    input3: "",
  });

  const handleInputChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setInputs((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    }));
  };

  return (
    <div className="top_page_container">
      <div className={styles.voucher_container}>
        <input
          maxLength={3}
          className={styles.voucher_input}
          name="input1"
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          value={inputs.input1}
        ></input>
        <input
          maxLength={3}
          className={styles.voucher_input}
          name="input2"
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          value={inputs.input2}
        ></input>
        <input
          maxLength={3}
          className={styles.voucher_input}
          name="input3"
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          value={inputs.input3}
        ></input>
      </div>
      <Button
        style={{
          width: "16em",
        }}
        onClick={handleSubmit}
      >
        Submit
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

My CSS

```
.voucher_input {
  width: 6ch;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  border-radius: 0.24em;
  padding: 0.2em;
  text-align: center;
}
.modal_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To implement the behavior you want, you'll need to add a bit more logic to your handleInputChange function. Here are the steps you'd want to follow:

Update the input field that the user typed into.
If the length of the value in that field reaches the maxLength, shift focus to the next input field.
If the user is pasting a string, split the string into sections of 3 digits each and update all input fields.
Below is an example of how you could implement this.

```
export default function VoucherPage() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [secret, setSecret] = useState<string>("");
  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState<SecretCode>({
    input1: "",
    input2: "",
    input3: "",
  });

  const inputRefs = useRef([React.createRef(), React.createRef(), React.createRef()]);

  const handleInputChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>, inputIndex: number) => {
    let inputValue = e.target.value;

    // Check if user is pasting
    if(inputValue.length > 3) {
      let parts = inputValue.match(/.{1,3}/g); // split string into parts of length 3
      setInputs({
        input1: parts[0] || '',
        input2: parts[1] || '',
        input3: parts[2] || '',
      });
    } else {
      setInputs(prevState => ({...prevState, [e.target.name]: inputValue}));

      if(inputValue.length === 3 && inputIndex < 2) {
        // focus the next input field
        inputRefs.current[inputIndex + 1].current.focus();
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="top_page_container">
      <div className={styles.voucher_container}>
        <input
          ref={inputRefs.current[0]}
          maxLength={3}
          className={styles.voucher_input}
          name="input1"
          onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e, 0)}
          value={inputs.input1}
        ></input>
        <input
          ref={inputRefs.current[1]}
          maxLength={3}
          className={styles.voucher_input}
          name="input2"
          onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e, 1)}
          value={inputs.input2}
        ></input>
        <input
          ref={inputRefs.current[2]}
          maxLength={3}
          className={styles.voucher_input}
          name="input3"
          onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e, 2)}
          value={inputs.input3}
        ></input>
      </div>
      <Button
        style={{
          width: "16em",
        }}
        onClick={handleSubmit}
      >
        Submit
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here, I've added an inputRefs ref array to hold references to your three input elements, so we can manually set focus to them. Also, I've added an inputIndex parameter to your handleInputChange function, which we use to decide which input field should be focused next. Finally, in the onChange props of your input elements, I've passed this index along with the event object.

Comment: thanks, but this only works for input by typing not pasting, for some reason when i paste it only enters 3 digits in first field. if i try to remove the max property then it works but the first input has all the characters and then next 2 have correct characters.